# How to make a TScrollbox out from TCustomControl?

Tags: delphi, custom-controls

I have created a component that has a paint override on the canvas and i would like to set a limit on minimum width and height. The scrollbar should appear at the side when the Width Or Height is less then the limit just like a scrollbox and can be scroll also.

i choose TCustomControl cause i paint and less flicker when double buffered.

any idea or better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TScrollBox` and `TCustomControl` both descend from `TWinControl`. `TScrollBox` and `TScrollingWinControl` add scroll bars, whereas `TCustomControl` adds a canvas. To get what you want, you can either add a canvas to a `TScrollingWinControl`, or you can add scroll bars to a `TCustomControl`.

Compare the definitions of the two classes (in *Forms.pas* and *Controls.pas*, respectively), and it should be clear which one's features will be easier to duplicate in your descendant. `TCustomControl` adds three simple methods, implemented in about 40 lines of code. Write a `TScrollingWinControl` descendant and copy the methods and properties from `TCustomControl` into it.