# Adding Canvas to TScrollBox

Tags: delphi

I am trying to do simple thing: Add a Canvas property on the TScrollBox descendant. I have read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627831/how-to-make-a-tscrollbox-out-from-tcustomcontrol)

but my ScrollBox descendant simply does not draw on the canvas. May anybody tell me, what is wrong?

```
  TfrmScrollContainer = class (TScrollBox)
  private
    FCanvas: TCanvas; 
    FControlState:TControlState;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  protected
    procedure Paint;
    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
    property Canvas: TCanvas read FCanvas;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);  override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

...  this is exact copy, how TWincontrol turns to TCustomControl (but it fails somewhere)

```
constructor TfrmScrollContainer.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FCanvas := TControlCanvas.Create;
  TControlCanvas(FCanvas).Control := Self;
end;

destructor TfrmScrollContainer.Destroy;
begin
  FCanvas.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TfrmScrollContainer.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  Include(FControlState, csCustomPaint);
  inherited;
  Exclude(FControlState, csCustomPaint);
end;

procedure TfrmScrollContainer.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
  FCanvas.Lock;
  try
    FCanvas.Handle := DC;
    try
      TControlCanvas(FCanvas).UpdateTextFlags;
      Paint;
    finally
      FCanvas.Handle := 0;
    end;
  finally
    FCanvas.Unlock;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmScrollContainer.Paint;    // this is not executed (I do not see any ellipse)
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color:=clRed;
  Canvas.Ellipse(ClientRect);
end;
```

Thanx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not including `csCustomPaint` to `ControlState`, you're including it to the similarly named field you declared. Your field is not checked, the ascendant control does not know anything about it. To solve, replace

```
procedure TfrmScrollContainer.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  Include(FControlState, csCustomPaint);
  inherited;
  Exclude(FControlState, csCustomPaint);
end;
```

with

```
procedure TfrmScrollContainer.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  ControlState := ControlState + [csCustomPaint];
  inherited;
  ControlState := ControlState - [csCustomPaint];
end;
```

Alternatively your scroll box may parent any control for your custom painting to work. The inherited `WM_PAINT` handler checks to see the control count and if it's not 0 it calls the paint handler instead of delivering the message to the default handler.

Comment: Yes, now it is working... just I have to check, why it is not properly repainting while resizing at design time... but excelent answer... thanx